# How do I make Villagers wear what I gift them

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I have been gifting my villagers a few outfits now. But after one or two days they usually revert to their standard outfits. 
I want them to keep the outfits I gift them, without those clothes only serving as furniture.
Also head and accessory slots keep reverting as well. The strangest thing about it is that they even revert, when I gift them something they actually like and which caters to their interests/colors.
Now I have seen that they put on gifted clothes again, even though they seem to change what they wear at random. But only if they like them enough and they match their style.

I would like to gift them a few outfits I deem fitting. But I feel like they will mismatch hats, accessory and clothes, if they wear those things at all.

I kinda feel like they have one Outfit they wear as "standard"  another one they wear if the weather is bad and then they also change into giftet outfits they like.

tldr.:

> **Is there a mechanism to get the villagers to wear what you want? Or is it just like in the older games, that you have to gift villagers an outfit over and over again, until it is the only clothing in all their "slots" so that they are forced to wear it?**

I would like an answer that will allow me to understand how the clothing mechanics work for villagers if possible.